# Edit JTable in Netbeans Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, matisse

I designed a  `JTable` with Netbeans Builder and I created 5 columns, the 5th one is `Boolean` so I want to know how to highlight whole the row when the user selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an easy way to color an entire row based on a value in the row.

The problem now is that only the cell is automatically repainted when you click on the checkbox so you will also need to add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel` so you can invoke a `repaint()` on the table row whenever the state of the checkbox is changed.

Comment: Nimbus L&F has an repainting issue with Boolen.Class, this is standard output without reseting renderer to default,

Comment: actually I tried before but I got many errors.show me in simple example by using Netbean Builder.

Comment: [partial answer for Nimbus L&F](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13012508/714968) by @kleopatra, but I think that setOpaque for Boolean class to sovle any issue

Comment: @user3104849, `show me in simple example by using Netbean Builder.` - I gave you a simple example. I  don't use an IDE to generate code for me. I write the code myself so I understand how the code works. I would rather spend time learning Swing then learning how to use an IDE.